# Is there a word to call the second rainbow above the first?

Tags: single-word-requests

As is known, a double rainbow is formed when there are two reflections inside a raindrop and a second rainbow, which tends to be fainter than the first, is distinguishable above the first.

Since in 'Shakespeare's Non-Standard English: A Dictionary of His Informal Language' by Norman Blake I found that, as an instance, 'water-gall' means 'small rainbow which at sea precede a storm', I began to wonder whether there is also a word to call that second rainbow. Is there?

Yes, I know that *second rainbow* or *secondary rainbow* or even *faint rainbow* can be used, but I'm looking for an informal or slangy name.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The specific one OP is talking about is called the [secondary rainbow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow) (as opposed to the *primary*).

There can be more than two. All except the primary are loosely called "supernumerary" rainbows, but [supernumerary/stacker rainbow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow#Supernumerary_rainbow) is also a specialised term for multiple bows appearing *inside* the primary, which are caused by [lightwave **interference**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interference_%28wave_propagation%29) rather than reflection by water droplets.

Answer (score 3):

It's usually called a *double rainbow* in the US.

Although I misunderstood the question originally (I did not realize that you were looking for a specific piece of a rainbow), apparently, the actual scientific term for the *primary* and *secondary* rainbows are just that, as explained by this [guide](http://www.eo.ucar.edu/rainbows/).

Comment: Yeah but that refers to both, not the one which is above specifically. Mind you, I doubt there _is_ a word for that.

Comment: @terdon: Huh, I misunderstood the question.  I'd agree that there really isn't a word...  I've updated my post to reflect the question properly.

Comment: @terdon I have heard people use "double rainbow" for specifically the second rainbow before, albeit confusingly.

Answer (score -1):

Without doubt, it is called a twobow.

Comment: Is this term used in the U.S. or in other anglophone countries?

Comment: All anglophone countries.

Comment: Please provide a source to go with your answer.

Comment: Yes, do. I've never heard of that term.

Comment: Allard, R. W.: Principles of Plant Breeding. J. Wiley & Sons Ltd., New York, London 1961